# Localization in Xcode, Base and Language string files

Tags: xcode, localization

I am having a lot of trouble getting any localization done in my app. I am trying to follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014. When I add a language to my project and it asks me which files to localize it only gives me the option to choose the LaunchScreen.xib, no option for the StoryBoard. Is this normal?

I am also confused about the Localizable.strings file. I created one and then clicked localize on it. I want to translate my app from English into traditional. I have the option of choosing "Base" "English" and "Chinese" for the strings file. What is the difference between Base and English? Which one do I need? Do I just need "Chinese", paste the strings and write the translations in that? It's all very confusing ......

Edit:

step by step: First I add the Chinese Language:

[image]

No option for the storyboard here. I want to extract the strings from the storyboard so I can add the Chinese translations. Next I click on the storyboard and click localize. I then choose Chinese:

[image]

This is what the storyboard looks like in the inspector now
:

[image]

Chinese is selected but there are no other files under the storyboard, no string files. It doesn't expand or anything. :

[image]

For some reason it has added some files for the launch screen though...What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your storyboard did not show up in the "Add Language" dialog and your xib file did was that the former was not yet marked for localization and the latter was. Had you first gone to your storyboard and clicked "Localize..." and selected "Base" for language, and *then* gone and added Chinese to the project, both files would have shown up in the list.

Which brings us to the second issue. The dialog message is ambiguous, but it is really asking you to select what language you want this storyboard file to correspond to (since you can have per-language .storyboard files). Given that this was your original storyboard, the right choice would have been "Base".

Comment: Thanks for that, figured it out in the end. Localisation is deff not my fave part of xcode.